# Displaying multiple values under same column using ag-grid

Tags: javascript, json, ag-grid

I have the following json data:

```
[
{"total_wt_arr_slp_buy":"-1.1411","total_wt_arr_last_slp_sell":"0.1308","total_exec_qty_buy":"1333409","total_ord_qty_sell":"1999840","total_wt_buy":"0.41","total_exec_qty_sell":"1859730","total_wt_ivwap_slp_sell":"-0.7283","total_wt_arr_last_slp_buy":"0.9204","total_wt_sell":"0.59","total_exec_val_sell":"106934063.00","total_wt_ivwap_slp_buy":"0.2858","total_exec_val_buy":"73297184.00","total_ord_qty_buy":"1456485","total_num_ords_sell":"2231","total_num_ords_buy":"1986","total_wt_arr_slp_sell":"-1.3096"}]
```

I'm using ag-grid to display this json data in the following way:

```
var columnDefs = [
     {headerName: "Orders", field: "total_num_ords_buy", width: 150, unSortIcon: true},
    {headerName: "Order Qty", field: "total_ord_qty_buy", width: 150, unSortIcon: true}, 

];

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFilter: true,

    suppressContextMenu: true,
    suppressMenuMainPanel: true,
    suppressMenuColumnPanel: true
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

    // do http request to get our sample data - not using any framework to keep the example self contained.
    // you will probably use a framework like JQuery, Angular or something else to do your HTTP calls.
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', '../dist/output3.json');
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
            var httpResult = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);


            function isNumeric(n) { 
                return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
            }

            var parsedData = httpResult.products.map(function(obj) {
                return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(memo, key) {
                    var value = obj[key];
                    memo[key] = isNumeric(value) ? Number(value) : value;

                    return memo;
                }, {})
            })

            console.log(parsedData);

            gridOptions.api.setRowData(parsedData);
        } 
    };
});
```

I want to display `total_num_ords_sell` under `Orders` `headerName` in the second row but when I do {`headerName: "Orders", field: "total_num_ords_sell", width: 150, unSortIcon: true},`, it creates a separate column for it as well. How do I do that?

Comment: I'm confused by your question, You say you want total_num_ords_sell in a second row and then say that it creates a "separate row"... sounds like you are getting what you want?

Comment: @JarodMoser It creates a separate column, I mean.

Comment: Ok... so you are trying to get the number 2231 to be displayed just below the number 1986, as shown in this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ccGkKntrpXd9KwjgIz3M?p=preview)? As in you want a bought row and sold row?